# How to append 1 component to file list of string in python

Tags: python, list

I have a file youtput.txt, with the following content:

`["bush", "bush", "harry", "harry", "mark", "mark", "messi", "messi", "obama", "obama", "ronaldo", "ronaldo", "stevejob", "stevejob", "suarez", "suarez", "trump", "trump"]`

I want to append "test" to this file so that the output will be:

`["bush", "bush", "harry", "harry", "mark", "mark", "messi", "messi", "obama", "obama", "ronaldo", "ronaldo", "stevejob", "stevejob", "suarez", "suarez", "trump", "trump", "test"]`

How can I do that?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/. If you have a more specific query, give a [mcve].

Comment: Is that `list` in the file just plain text (so basically a string)?

Comment: yes, above is its content that I copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the file into a `string`, `strip` the new-line, use `ast.literal_eval` to [convert the string to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python), `append` `"test"` and finally write to the same file after passing the `list` into the `str()` function:

```
import ast
l = ast.literal_eval(open("youtube.txt").read().strip())
l.append("test")
open("youtube.txt", "w").write(str(l))
```

Comment: thank you very much <3 <3. It work perfectly with me :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
data = None
with open('youroutput.txt') as store:
    data = eval(store.read())
data.append("test")

with open('youroutput.txt', 'w') as dump:
    dump.write(repr(data))
```

Comment: `eval` is extremely insecure. For instance, what if the contents of `"youroutput.txt"` were `__import__("os").system("rm -rf /")`?

Comment: I agree. But `eval` is okay if the content of the file is under user's control and seeing the beginner-type question, I made that assumption. Anyway, if "youroutput.txt" contained that the OP would get "permission denied" and we would get another question on SO ;-)

Comment: @KietNguyen You are welcome! If this answer worked for you, you can accept it by clicking the tick icon.